# Positioning for IOS Safari placing div too far down page

Tags: html, ios, css

I have been performing some testing on an Instagram widget I am developing. I cannot however get my head around why on Safari when you click on an Instagram image, it displays all the way down the page and not in the centre.

I do understand that this is because it is just displaying half way down the page, however it should respect the viewport of the device surely? It works perfectly on all desktop browsers.

Here is a link to a preview of the site:
http://alexwileymusethemes.businesscatalyst.com/

I have applied some CSS to the lightbox like so:

```
.fancybox-wrap{
    top: 50% !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: relative;
 }
```

This is pushing it all the way down the page for me. Any feedback welcomed and feel free to inspect the site using developer tools. To reiterate, this bug is only appearing on Safari IOS for iPhone / iPad.

Comment: Older Safari need to be prefixed with `-webkit-` as in `-webkit-transform:`.

Comment: @LGSon thanks for bringing that up, but it wouldn't explain why the div appears so far down the page in the first place

Comment: Quite the contrary, `top: 50%` will push it down and the transform pulls it back ... no transform and it will be half way down the page

Comment: @LGSon unfortunately it still has not worked as you can see by the link :/ This is also the newest version of Safari